# iPhone: How to Determine When a Download from a URL has Completed

Tags: iphone, download, nsurlconnection

I need to populate an array using data from a `NSURL`. How do I determine when the download from the URL has completed?

Comment: Depend on how you're doing the download. Post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You usually use NSURLConnection and then set its delegate to whatever object controls the download. When NSURLConnection finishes it sends `connectionDidFinishLoading:` to the delegate to signal completion.

See the [URL System Programming Guide.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Answer (score 0):

there is delegate method will be called when all the data from url is download.`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {}`